# Why check if current sum is more than smallest current sum when finding smallest sum? (Triplet Sum Close to Target algorithms question)

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this coding problem:
**Given an array of unsorted numbers and a target number, find a triplet in the array whose sum is as close to the target number as possible, return the sum of the triplet. If there are more than one such triplet, return the sum of the triplet with the smallest sum.** I have a question about a portion of the solution and I've elaborated more on it further below, after the entire answer to the coding question directly below this pargraph. Entire solution:

```
class TripletSumCloseToTarget {
    
      public static int searchTriplet(int[] arr, int targetSum) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length < 3)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int smallestDifference = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
          int left = i + 1, right = arr.length - 1;
          while (left < right) {
            // comparing the sum of three numbers to the 'targetSum' can cause overflow
            // so, we will try to find a target difference
            int targetDiff = targetSum - arr[i] - arr[left] - arr[right];
            if (targetDiff == 0) //  we've found a triplet with an exact sum
              return targetSum; // return sum of all the numbers
    
            // the second part of the above 'if' is to handle the smallest sum when we have 
            // more than one solution
            if (Math.abs(targetDiff) < Math.abs(smallestDifference)
                || (Math.abs(targetDiff) == Math.abs(smallestDifference) 
                                       && targetDiff > smallestDifference))
              smallestDifference = targetDiff; // save the closest and the biggest difference
    
            if (targetDiff > 0)
              left++; // we need a triplet with a bigger sum
            else
              right--; // we need a triplet with a smaller sum
          }
        }
        return targetSum - smallestDifference;
      }
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
           TripletSumCloseToTarget.searchTriplet(new int[] { -2, 0, 1, 2 }, 2));
        System.out.println(
           TripletSumCloseToTarget.searchTriplet(new int[] { -3, -1, 1, 2 }, 1));
        System.out.println(
           TripletSumCloseToTarget.searchTriplet(new int[] { 1, 0, 1, 1 }, 100));
        System.out.println(
           TripletSumCloseToTarget.searchTriplet(new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 6 }, 5));
      }
    }
```

From the above code, this portion is used to continuously check for the lowest sum to obtain the smallest solution.

```
 // the second part of the above 'if' is to handle the smallest sum when we have 
        // more than one solution
        if (Math.abs(targetDiff) < Math.abs(smallestDifference)
            || (Math.abs(targetDiff) == Math.abs(smallestDifference) 
                                   && targetDiff > smallestDifference))
          smallestDifference = targetDiff; // save the closest and the biggest difference
```

However, I'm unsure in what cases the below portion would be needed. Aren't we checking for the lowest difference? Why check if the current difference is more than a smallest difference? Shouldn't making sure the current difference is less than the smallest difference suffice?

```
&& targetDiff > smallestDifference)
```

Would really appreciate some insight regarding this portion of the solution. Thanks!!

Comment: `targetDiff` is a positive number when the sum of the three numbers is less than the target. So for example if `targetDiff` is 5 and `smallestDifference` is -5, then you want to select the three numbers that gave you `targetDiff`.

Answer (score -1):

### **Official answer (from original question creator)**:

### (+ve case):

This problem is asking to find a triplet with two conditions. 1) Closest to the target 2) If there are more than one such triplet, find the triplet with the smallest sum.

For example: Array [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 6], Target = 5

We have two solutions here: (1, 1, 2) & (0, 0, 6). Both these solutions are exactly "1" away from "5". Between these two solutions, the correct answer will be (1, 1, 2) as it has sum "4" which is less than the sum of the other triplet which is "6".

### Own explanation (-ve case)

Illustrating condition 2: Example when a target sum is -ve, e.g. -5, and you have two triplets a: {-1, -1, -1,}  and b: {-5, -1,-1} when you calculate their difference with -5 (i.e. -5 - (sum of b or a)), triplet a will equals -2, triplet b will equal +2, modulus of both means they are exactly “2” away from “5”. Between those two solutions, the correct answer will be {-5, -1, -1} as it has a sum of -7 which is less than the sum of the other triplet which is - 3. Just ask, is the statement -7<-3? Because it’s true, triplet b which sums up to -7 is the answer.

### Another way of viewing the problem

Another way is to visualize the target sum and sum of each triplet on a number line. If two triplets are at the same distance, the triplet with smaller sum i.e. sum(a)<sum(b) is the answer.